# How do I test if input is not /dev/random?

Tags: node.js

I have a simple chat server that I am playing with and I am trying to secure it. I have Node.js listening on a port accepting all input from all clients and that back to all clients. I am able to flood the server by doing

```
cat /dev/random | chat
```

Where chat is the client app. It floods the server and every client. I know I can just test to see if input is longer than some given amount, like 500 characters, but it is flooding the server (the check needs to be on the server, not the client cause I could just telnet as well).

I think I need to check to make sure there are no control characters in the input, but still allow all the random UNICODE. How would I do this? What are all the characters that could be bad?

EDIT: I am adding some rate limiting so they can't just flood the server. I am adding logic to test if the average post time is below a certain threshold and closing their connect if it is. But I didn't have a question on how to do that :)

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/random` or control characters aren't the problem -- someone could still spam your server with a random text-only stream. A better way is to rate-limit your clients, so that you accept only a certain amount of data within a time interval. For example, if a client sends more than 500 bytes within a second, you could mute that client for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably better off writing a script to do this.

1. you can tailor it to output certain characters or filter certain chars
2. you can replay bad sequences to test your fixes
3. you can throttle it
4. you can manipulate real UNICODE rather than just rely on the random output you're getting (I appreciate that testing with random byte sequences is probably good, but is likely a subset of what you really want to do)

You may choose to get your script to use `/dev/random` under the covers, but it's a more extensible option to write a script.

Comment: Actually a friend of mine wrote this server and I am both trying to break his server and fix it. Someone else flooded it with /dev/random, so now I am trying to prevent that.